# TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable - in open of pdf file with python

Tags: python, pdf

Good day,

I want to open the pdf files that have a specific name from a directory . These file names are provided from a csv file input, which are in the second column.

I tried the follwing code, but I received an error message:

> TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable

How can I solve this problem and the pdf files to be opened
    according the input file?

And another issue: how can I fix if the
        input name is not an exact match with the pdf title,but I still want
        to open this file that contain the input name?

```
import csv
import os
from pathlib import *

dir_path = Path('D:\\path\\pdf files')
pdf_files = dir_path.glob('*.pdf')

file1=open('INPUT.csv','r')
reader=csv.reader(file1,delimiter=';')
for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    for item in reader:
        file_name=item[1]
        print(file_name)#just to see the file name that I want to open 
        if file_name in pdf_file:
            os.startfile("%s"%(pdf_file))
file1.close()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem in line `if file_name in pdf_file`: `pdf_file` is not string, but instance of `pathlib.Path`, use [name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) to get file name as string:

```
if file_name == pdf_file.name
```

In case you want to check if `file_name` without ext contains in `pdf_file` name:

```
file_name.split('.')[-2] in f.name  # ('example' in 'some_example.pdf') == True
```

Comment: I asked a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68938983/4999991). I would appreciate if you could take a look at that one too. 