# Listing all the modules/subpackages in the NXOpen package

Tags: python, nxopen

I am trying to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1707786/4999991), to list all the modules in the NX Open package:

```py
import NXOpen
import pkgutil

the_string = ""

package = NXOpen
for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(package.__path__):
    the_string = the_string + modname + "\n"


lw = NXOpen.Session.GetSession().ListingWindow
lw.Open()
lw.WriteFullline(the_string)
lw.Close()
```

but I get the below error message:

> pkgutil.py, line 123, in iter_modules raise ValueError("path must be None or list of path to look for")

What is the problem and how can I resolve it?

**P.S. 1.** I checked the `NXOpen.__path__` attribute. It is a string type property with a value of `NXOpenPackagePath`!

**P.S. 2.** I asked a follow up question, [here on the SIEMENS PLM forum](https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/question/0D54O000075NA2nSAG/why-nxopenpath-doesnt-return-its-path).

**P.S.3.** I also tried the

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(Path(os.path.dirname(NXOpen.__file__))):
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/248862/4999991) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51309751/4999991), but now I get the error:

> TypeError: 'WindowsPath' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/94a3d2a6329ab7941e93ad2f5bcbb8af2b8b80d2/Lib/pkgutil.py#L122) of `iter_modules`, it expects list argument, while you pass a `Path` [object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path).

Please, try just `pkgutil.iter_modules([os.path.dirname(NXOpen.__file__)])`.

Comment: I had already tried that. I get the same `ValueError: path must be None or list of paths to look for modules in`

Comment: @Foad I've edited the answer. Kindly try `pkgutil.iter_modules([os.path.dirname(NXOpen.__file__)])`

Comment: strangely enough, adding the square brackets `[...]`  helped!